# Running phoenix server and independent elixir app together

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I am beginner in elixir. I am working on api . It is run directly from mix by  using command `iex -S mix` . This app includes chat_server and  api server. It has seperate `mix.exs` file.

I also need to create website for login/logout functionality for session handling in backend. I am using phoenix for that. Is has it command to start the server `mix phoenix.server`

They both has common database and modules.

So, I am thinking to run these two together from single mix file. 
Should i create different `mix.exs` for web server and handle them two different apps or is it possible to run from single `mix.exs` file. 
what if one app crashes?

Is it possible to define multiple apps inside this block?

```
def application do
    # Specify extra applications you'll use from Erlang/Elixir
    [
      mod: { MYAPP, [] },
      extra_applications: [
                            :logger,
                            :gproc,
                            :mongodb_ecto,
                            :ecto,
                            :ecto_mnesia,
                            :comeonin,
                            :bamboo,
                            :bamboo_smtp,
                            :phoenix,
                            :phoenix_html,
                            :cowboy,
                            :gettext
                          ]
    ]
  end
```

Comment: It’s really hard to advise one approach over another one without knowing more details. Do `chat_server` and `api server` deserve their own `application`, or they could be just `GenServer`s (in most cases `GenServer` is perfectly enough and is easier to supervise/control.) If both are to remain applications, why won’t you use [_umbrella project_](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html) to control the structure? The only question that is easy to answer is: it is not possible to define multiple apps as a single application.

Comment: @mudasobwa chat_server and api server are GenServers

Comment: N apps in 1 = umbrella app